# How to make a reproducible data sample in PowerBI using Python?

Tags: python, random, powerbi

This is a self-answered post. Why? Because many questions in Power BI go unanswered because of lacking data samples. Also, many seem to wonder how to edit data tables in Power BI using Python. And, of course, the world needs a more wide-spread usage of Python in Power BI. Some think that you have to apply a Python snippet to an existing table loaded elsewhere. My answer to this post will show you how to build a (fairly big) data sample with a few lines of code in an otherwise empty Power BI file.

**So, how can you build a data sample and make changes to it using Python in Power BI?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll show you how to build a dataset of `10000` rows that contains both categorical and numerical values. I'm using the Python libraries [numpy](https://numpy.org/) and [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for the data generation and table operations, respectively. The snippet below simply draws a random element from two lists `10000` times to build two columns with a few street and city names, and adds a list of random numbers into the mix. Then I'm using pandas to organize the data in a dataframe. Using Python in the `Power BI Power Query Editor`, your input has to be a table, and your output has to be a pandas dataframe.

**Python snippet:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)
streets=['Broadway', 'Bowery', 'Houston Street']
cities=['New York', 'Chicago', 'Baltimore']

rows = 1000

lst_cities=np.random.choice(cities,rows).tolist()
lst_streets=np.random.choice(streets,rows).tolist()
lst_numbers= np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=rows).tolist()
df_dataset=pd.DataFrame({'City':lst_cities,
                      'Street':lst_streets,
                      'ID':lst_numbers})
df_metadata = pd.DataFrame([df_dataset.shape])
```

**Power BI:**

In Power BI Desktop, click `Enter Data` to go to the `Power Query Editor`. In the following dialog window, do absolutely nothing but clicking `OK`. The result is an empty table and two steps under `Applied steps`:

[image]

Now, use `Transform > Run Python Script`, insert the snippet above and click `OK` to get this:

[image]

You now have a preliminary table with 2 columns and 3 rows. And this is a pretty neat detail of the implementation of Python in Power BI. These are three different datasets that are made available to you after running your snippet. `Dataset` is constructed by default, but is empty since we started out with an empty table. If we started out with some other data, the first line of the `Run Python Script` explains the purpose of this table `# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script`. And it is constructed in the form of a pandas dataframe. The last table `df_metadata` is only a brief description of the dataset we're really interested in: `df_dataset`, but I've added it to the mix in order to illustrate that all dataframes made by you in your snippet will be available to you. You chose which table to continue working on by clicking `Table` next to the name.

[image]

And that's it! You now have a table of mixed datatypes to keep working on either using Python or Power BI itself:

[image]

**From here you can:**

1. Keep working on your table using any menu option
2. Insert another Python script
3. Duplicate your original dataframe and keep working on another version by creating a `Reference` by right-clicking `Table` under `Queries`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Great explanation vestland. I'm adding another way without python.

---

### 1. Open Power Query and select "Enter data"

[image: Enter data]

---

### 2. Enter or paste data

You can enter your data manually or - way easier and faster - copy it from Excel or any other structured table into the GUI.

[image: Copy&Paste data from Excel]

---

### 3. Load data and copy M-Code

When you have loaded the data, open the advanced editor and copy the full code:

[image: Open advanced editor]

And copy the code into your question, like:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUTICYmOlWJ1oJRMgyxSIzcA8cyDLAogtlWJjAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Col1 = _t, Col2 = _t, Col3 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Col1", Int64.Type}, {"Col2", Int64.Type}, {"Col3", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

The binary at the beginning of the code contains the entire structure of the table. This makes it very easy for everyone who wants to help.

---

Comment: Very nice approach! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Please upvote if ok for you to help getting attention to it. Most PBI questions still don't have useful data.