# Power BI: How to process/clean string data using Python?

Tags: python, powerbi

I am getting started with Power BI. I have a data set set up in Power BI and in editor I am trying to use python.

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script

dataset = dataset['word' in dataset['Title']]
```

Basically I want to remove the rows in which the column title does not contain the word "word". Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dataset[~dataset['title'].str.contains('word')]` where the `~` operator takes care of the `not in` part of the procedure.

**Example:** *Combining the powers of PowerBI and Python*

Lets look at a made-up example of a dataset with `good`, `bad` or `mediocre` movies of some `category` and a column with an `ID` . If you take a look at the post [How to make a reproducible data sample in PowerBI using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58457137/how-to-make-a-reproducible-data-sample-in-powerbi-using-python) you can see how to insert a sample dataset in PowerBI using Python. And the post [Power BI: Using Python on multiple tables in the Query Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947441/power-bi-using-python-on-multiple-tables-in-the-query-editor/51947461#51947461) will show you alle the details of the procedure that follows here:

If you use the PowerQuery Editor toinsert a python snippet like this:

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script

import pandas as pd

df_dataset = pd.DataFrame({'title': {0: 'bad movie',
  1: 'mediocre movie',
  2: 'bad movie',
  3: 'bad movie',
  4: 'good movie',
  5: 'bad movie',
  6: 'bad movie',
  7: 'mediocre movie'},
 'category': {0: 'drama',
  1: 'comedy',
  2: 'drama',
  3: 'comedy',
  4: 'action',
  5: 'comedy',
  6: 'drama',
  7: 'comedy'},
 'ID': {0: 32, 1: 46, 2: 96, 3: 25, 4: 83, 5: 78, 6: 36, 7: 96}})
```

... you'll end up wiht a table like this:

[image]

Now, inserting a new python snippet like this:

```
df_notbad = dataset[~dataset['title'].str.contains('bad')]
```

... will give you a dataset where all rows with `'bad'` are removed:

[image]

You will have to look at the linked resources to sort out all the details, but please don't hesitate to let me know if some of the details are unclear!