# Power BI DAX - sum all of one column but keyed off different table

Tags: powerbi, dax

This FEELS like something that can be done but I am at a loss for how to do it.

I have a table that has applicants for jobs...
name, requisition id, division, date applied, date hired

Each row is an applicant. Obviously not all applicants are hired. So in every row all fields are filled out with the exception of **date hired** for applicants that have not been hired.

I have slicers for **month/quarter/year** and **division**.
The date slicers all key off a field in every table called data_as_of which is the last day of the month with a one-to-many relationship with a date dimension table.

Here is a sample table...
[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQO9d.png

So here is what I'd like to do.
I'd like to slice by year and show a visual of all people hired in that year. Same with Quarter and Month (ie count all people in that quarter or month as appropriate). So far so good.  That's easy.

Now on the same report page I'd like to show a visual (assume bar charts) that shows me a count of all the people that applied to the same **requisition id** prior to the **date hired** of whomever was hired in that **requisition id**.

Using the example above...
All of these examples assume 2021.
So if I used the month slicer in December I'd get 2 hirees in HR, Diane and Mel.  In the second visual I'd get 7 Applicants.

If I used the month slicer to show November I'd get two hirees - Rhys and Jody. The applicant visual would show me 8 applicants. All 6 from **requisition id** 4 and 2 from **requisition id** 2 because one applied after Rhys was hired.

Consequently if I sliced for April of 2021 I'd get 1 hiree - Remi. In the applicant visual I'd get  4 applicants who all applied prior to Remi's hire date (including Morgan who applied in March but wasn't hired until May).

Does that all make sense?

I very much appreciate your help.

Best regards,
~Don

Comment: Hi, please provide a reproducible MVE (minimal, workable example). [In this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70773971/12242625) you'll find two ways how you easily can share data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.