# How to create Daily , Hourly ,week and Month filters dynamically change in Column chart when i change in Slicer selection?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Im Having the Two Years Data , I want to show that data Dynamically in column Chart when i change the Parameters of Daily Hourly Weekly and Monthly Basis in Slicer Selection... What Type Of Measures And What Type Of Steps I need to Do By the Way Of Dax. Main Parameter Is weekly Basis How it will

Comment: Hi, please provide a reproducible MVE (minimal, workable example). [In this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70773971/12242625) you'll find two ways how you easily can share data. Additionally, please explain what you already have tried and where you stuck.

Comment: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/Dynamic-Date-Slicer-including-a-Week-and-Quarter-option/m-p/2285451/highlight/false#M56040 Please Go through This Link This is what i was prepared with the help of that ... I want to show in Weekly and Hourly Basis as like they are showing in Daily Monthly and Yearly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.